# How to run DropDownList change event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Hello i trying to change ddl.selectedIntex=1,i see that value of ddl is changing but event ddl.change did't work.

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

This just set the value but i need to run the .change function

any ideas?
I try this in console all works thx,meybe you know how can i do this by passing the PostData to the HttpWebRequest?

I try this in console all works thx,meybe you know how can i do this by passing the PostData to the HttpWebRequest
I added my code

```
HttpWebRequest postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.com/Pages/current.aspx");
PostString += "ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$AccountsDDL$ddlAccounts=" + Number + "&";//Here
 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostString);
    postRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream newStream = postRequest.GetRequestStream();
    newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    newStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)postRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: use `__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts','');` 
or `$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts").change()`

Comment: I try this in console all works thx,meybe you know how can i do this by passing the PostData to the HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change event is not triggered when value is changed through code. You need to call `change()` or `trigger("change")`

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts").change()
```

or

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts").trigger("change")
```

As a *additional note* use the [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the element in javascript instead of using the hard coded asp.net generated client id.

```
$("#<%= ddlAccounts.ClientID %>").change()
```

Comment: Adil is right, change event is not fired in case that value is changed programmatically (by javascript).

Comment: `$('[id$="ddlAccounts"]')` can also be used to get the element.

Comment: Yes, but I think that is less efficient way as it will have to search for matching element instead of directly getting the element.

Comment: `$("#<%= ddlAccounts.ClientID %>")` will not work if the scripts are placed in `.js` file. In that case `$("#dllAccounts")` can be used provided with attribute `ClientIdMode = "static"` for the `DropDownList` or `$('[id$="ddlAccounts"]')` can be used if `ClientIdMode` property is not set.

Comment: Can you help me with sending data to HttpWebRequest  i added new  code on top

Comment: Yes @Bharadwaj, $("dllAccounts") would be $("#dllAccounts")

Comment: @user256406, this is good example for ajax call,  http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

or just use this

```
$("[id$=ddlAccounts]").change();
```

use of $ 'Ends with' to shorten the name of selector

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
        $("select").change(function () {
            var str = "";
            $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
                $("#DropDownList1")[0].selectedIndex = 5;
            });
            $("div").text(str);
        }).change();

    </script>
    <div></div>
```

Try this.... it may help you